# f2py fails because of Attribute-Error in python

Tags: python, fortran, gfortran, f2py

I am trying to use a Fortran 95 function in Python 3.10 with f2py.
I compile as follows:

```
python -m numpy.f2py -c -m isprim f2p.f95
```

My F95-Code:

```
function isprima (p)
    integer, intent(in) :: p
    integer :: i
    logical :: isprima
    isprima = .true.
    if (p/=2) then
        testloop: do i=2,int(floor(sqrt(real(p))))
            if (modulo(p, i) == 0)  then
                isprima = .false.
                exit testloop
            end if
        end do testloop
    end if
end function isprima
```

My Python-Code:

```
import numpy as np
import isprim
print(isprim.isprima(5))
```

The error-message is:

> Exception has occurred: AttributeError module 'isprim' has no
> attribute 'isprima'   File
> "C:\Users\josch\Documents\Programmierung\Fortran95\fortran2python.py",
> line 3, in 
> print(isprim.isprima(5)) AttributeError: module 'isprim' has no attribute 'isprima'

I don't know what is wrong.

When I tried to solve it by myself, I found solutions on the internet, for instance to name the F95-Function in lowercase. It didn't work, obviously. I couldn't find other solutions.

Comment: _I don't know what is wrong_ We don't either, because you did not share the full error message.

Comment: I am so Sorry, I forgot it. I edited it now, so everyody can see the error.

Comment: Welcome, do not use version tags if not necessaey to specify a specific version. And even then you should typically also use the generic tag like tag [tag:fortran]. See the instructions for each tag disolayed when adding them.

Comment: Have you looked at isprim.py to see what it contains?

Comment: There is no other module or program named isprim.py. But I tried to rename the whole module, sothat there is definently no other module, that could interfiere. But that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you try building using

```
f2py -c f2p.f95 -m isprim
```

or

```
python -m numpy.f2py -c f2p.f95 -m isprim
```

On Linux, it will generate a .so file.  This will be picked up by the python program when it runs.  Not strictly necessary to include numpy - it just makes the execution time a bit longer since numpy has to be loaded

```
import isprim
print(isprim.isprima(5))
print(isprim.isprima(6))
```

The result is

```
1
0
```

**Edit**

If running on windows, f2py will generate two files.  If the module name specified (-m) is fred

1. A pyd file (fred.[python version].pyd)
2. A dll (fred.libs\libf2p[some hex string and text].dll

Copy the DLL and the pyd file to the same directory as the python test program.  In my case, after building, I had

```
U:\fortran\f2py>dir
 Volume in drive U has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 78EE-1692

 Directory of U:\fortran\f2py

09/03/2024  06:59    <DIR>          .
09/03/2024  06:32    <DIR>          ..
09/03/2024  06:32               375 f2p.f90
09/03/2024  06:59    <DIR>          isprim
09/03/2024  06:59            27,136 isprim.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
09/03/2024  06:34                67 primtest.py
               3 File(s)         27,578 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  48,000,462,848 bytes free

U:\fortran\f2py>python primtest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "U:\fortran\f2py\primtest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import isprim
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing isprim: The specified module could not be found.

U:\fortran\f2py>copy isprim\.libs\*.dll .
isprim\.libs\libf2p.2AL5PRFC2YGEOTFQS23JZ4KOAGPGXN3J.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
        1 file(s) copied.

U:\fortran\f2py>python primtest.py
1
0
```

If you are using visual studio, you can use dumpbin to find out what DLLs, the pyd is looking for.  In my case

```
U:\fortran\f2py>dumpbin /dependents isprim.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.29.30151.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file isprim.cp39-win_amd64.pyd

File Type: DLL

  Image has the following dependencies:

    libf2p.2AL5PRFC2YGEOTFQS23JZ4KOAGPGXN3J.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
    python39.dll
    KERNEL32.dll
    VCRUNTIME140.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll

  Summary

        2000 .data
        1000 .pdata
        2000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
        4000 .text
```

Comment: Okay, ut I am on windows and it creates a folder named isprim with a dll file in it. When I try to import it like "import isprim" it doesn't recognise the import.

Comment: It should be the same name as the DLL up to the first dot.  So if it is isprime.cpython...dll, then it should be isprime.  Try moving the dll to the directory with the python script.

Comment: The name of the created dll is "libtst.IGGBQL63Q5NMCT2BAXMU6QYSU6ERO5I5.gfortran-win_amd64.dll". And it doesn't work, even whem moving it. I think I will switch to Linux for projects, that require both python and fortran 95

Comment: What C compiler do you have installed?

Comment: "gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0" is my current compiler I think. I used MinGW to install it.

Comment: I've edited my post for a windows environment.  Was a pyd created?